# Xcode 13.2.1 does not make an executable using command line tool template

Tags: swift, xcode13

template does not create a executable file.  Does anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does.

The build folder is not shown in the project navigator anymore.

Choose "Show Build Folder in Finder" in the menu `Product`

Comment: Thank you, Vadian, for your response, however, on my system mini m1 running 12.1 and Xcode Version 13.2.1 (13C100) "show derived data folder in finder" does show folders for index > Build > Products > Debug but the Debug folder is empty.  The Xcode is plain out of the template loaded and built for "my mac".  Any suggestions?

Comment: After I posted the above comment, found upon exploration, that "show derived data folder in finder" actually does not point to  the real build folder, which is one level up and does contain Build > Products > Debug > myTest1 unix executable code.  Thanks!